# ORA-00936: missing expression for WHERE (ID Mod 2) = 0;

Tags: sql, oracle

With SQL as below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY
  FROM STATION 
  WHERE Int([ID] Mod 2) = 0;
```

I got error message:

```
WHERE Int([ID] Mod 2) = 0 
* 
ERROR at line 2: 
ORA-00936: missing expression
```

And I also tried:

```
  WHERE (ID Mod 2) <> 1;
```

but I still got the same error.

Comment: Perhaps `mod(id, 2)` or `id % 2`?

Comment: If in doubt [read the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions113.htm#SQLRF00668)

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) The answer, *"A lot. An absurd amount. More than you think you are capable of. After you have reached the end of your rope and the pain of not having the answer exceeds the vast amount of shame received by posting your question, that's when you can go ahead and ask. Because at that point, you will have done whatever research necessary to make it a good question worth asking!"*

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm.  I would expect:

```
WHERE MOD(ID, 2) = 0;
```

Two things:

- `MOD()` is a function.
- Oracle doesn't use square braces to delimit identifiers, as far as I know.

Comment: Aren't you missing a parenthesis?

Comment: @Impaler . . . No, not a parentheses.  I didn't delete all the characters I thought I had.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY
FROM STATION 
WHERE Mod(ID,2) = 0;
```

Comment: Brackets are not supported in Oracle.

Comment: Updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct city
  from station 
  where mod(id,2) = 0;
```

Comment: You should add some context to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT CITY
FROM STATION 
WHERE Mod(ID,2) = 0;

is working. Thank you very much.